# Looking for Code to turn text Fields into variables?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm looking for a code to be able to turn for text fields into variables for an equation. I've got the text fields set up and when clicked they pulled up a numpad, I just need to link them. Suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean with linking textfields

Comment: If you want good answers, you first have to write a somewhat comprehensible question.  Now, there are lots of folks on here willing to help, but you have to give them more to go on than that...

Comment: Improper terminology. I meant string. What I'm looking for is to make each text box be a variable so that I can textfield can be strung together to make an equation. tF1 = x tF2 = y tF3 = z etc. So I can make each one be an input to affect tF4 = output. x+y+z=tF4
Is that any better?

Answer (score 1):

without more detail i cant really help
but for extracting something from a textfield

just get the string form the textfield, then convert to int?

```
NSString *variable = textfield.text;
int x= [variable intValue];
```

Comment: Simaple way is int x= [textfield.text intValue];

Comment: This looks the route that I'm going. Thanks.